# Where is volatile needed in C++ objects handling interrupt service routines

Tags: c++, interrupt, volatile

I am designing a hardware driver for an embedded system in C++.  From my research and experimentation, I know that it is possible to "glue" together interrupt services routines and object member methods as so:

```
struct Hardware {
   volatile uint32_t CR; //Control register
   volatile uint32_t SR; //Status register
   volatile uint8_t DR; //Data register
};

class Driver {
public:
    static void sIsr() { 
        for (auto h = _handlers.begin(); h != _handlers.end(); h++) {
            (*h)->isr();
        }
    }

    Driver() {
        //Assume I have a method which disables interrupts temporarily
        enterCriticalSection();
        {
            //Register myself
            _handlers.push_back(this);
        }
        exitCriticalSection();
    }

    ~Driver() {
        enterCriticalSection();
        {
            //Un-register myself
            _handlers.remove(this);
        }
        exitCriticalSection();
    }

    size_t available() {
        if (_tail < _head) return _head - _tail;
        //Assume I also handle wrap-around conditions
    }

    size_t read(uint8_t* dest, size_t maxLength) {
        enterCriticalSection();
        {

            size_t realLength = std::min(maxLength, available());

            //Assume I also handle wrap-around conditions
            std::copy(_data[_tail], _data[_tail] + realLength, dest);

            _tail += realLength;
        }
        exitCriticalSection();

        return realLength;
    }

protected:
    void isr() {
       //Read data from the hardware register into our buffer
       _data[_head] = _hardware->DR;
       //Assume I handler overflows/wrap-around conditions here as well...

      _head++;
    }

private:
    static std::list<Driver*> _handlers;

    Hardware* _hardware;
    
    uint8_t _data[128];
    uint8_t* _head;
    uint8_t* _tail;
};

//Assume this is the ISR function called form the interrupt vector
void Hardware_ISR() {
    Driver::sIsr();
}
```

My question is, since all of the member variables of Driver are accessed from both an ISR and the normal program flow, do they all need to be marked as volatile?  If so, are there an issues with the member methods accessing these volatile values?  Is this even the correct approach for something like this?

Also, there may be some syntax errors in the above code, this is just an example I wrote up for this question.

Comment: If you have a complex data structure accessible from both normal code and ISR, then `volatile` alone won't help you. You need some mechanism for locking the data to prevent access when it is being modified by the other part of the code.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Which is what I am doing with the critical sections (which disable interrupts).  However, even with those, would volatile still be needed?

Comment: Things that you protect with critical sections normally do not need to be volatile.

Comment: Clarification: the standard does not require this, but in practice it works. The compiler should not be able to deduce that variables protected by critical sections do not change by the normal code, because it should not be able to see through an invocation of disable_interrupts(). So it must assume that disable_interrupts() can call any function and change any variable. Which is what you need to prevent optimisations that are usually prevented by declaring variables `volatile`.

Comment: At one time volatile was the mainstay of embedded programming but with more modern compilers its use should be limited to memory mapped hardware registers where you don't want the compiler eliminating reads or writes that it may think redundant. Best to use mutexes, atomics, and such for threads and leave volatile for hardware manipulation.

Comment: If the _data array were filled by a DMA (rather than from code like I have shown) would that be a good use for volatile because the compiler needs to be told to always read from memory?